# Actionscript 3.0 drawRect works weird

Tags: actionscript-3, drawrect

I have a BitmapData object named myBitmapData. It was loaded of PNG of size 104x104. This PNG represents a red circle on the transparent background.
There is also a Sprite object named myBackground. I want render that red circle into myBackground.

```
myBackground.graphics.beginBitmapFill(myBitmapData);
myBackground.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, myBitmapData.width, myBitmapData.height);
myBackground.graphics.endFill();
addChild(myBackground);
```

Everything is fine. I see a red circle in the left top of myBackground.

But when I change the third line to

```
myBackground.graphics.drawRect(0, 52, myBitmapData.width, myBitmapData.height);
```

and expect my circle to be translated 52 pixels down, I actually obtain something strange (for me :)): there are two red half-circles (they form like hourglass).

So, the question is: how do I render myBitmapData into the random position of myBackground?

P.S.
In the case of

```
myBackground.graphics.drawRect(0, 104, myBitmapData.width, myBitmapData.height);
```

it is circle again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by [beginBitmapFill](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#beginBitmapFill%28%29)'s default `repeat = true` parameter. There's an example in the docs. Disabling the repetition won't work though, you'd just get a half circle then.

There are several ways to fix this:

- Use a [Matrix](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html) with a translation (displacement) as argument in `beginBitmapFill`.
- Draw the rectangle at `0,0` on another Sprite, and move that sprite to where you want it on the background.
- Don't draw directly to the background, but to another bitmap using [*copyPixels*](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels%28%29). Then fill the background with that bitmap.